# Is it safe to pass C++11 std::function to a legacy function that takes boost::function

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, lambda, std-function

We have a legacy system that uses **boost::function** intensively, now it's decided to move to newer modern C++ standards. Suppose we have a legacy function like this:

```
void someFunction(boost::function<void(int)>);
```

Is it safe to directly pass in a C++11 function?

```
//calling site, new C++11 code
std::function<void(int)> func = [](int x){
    //some implementation
}
someFunction(func); //will this always work?
```

Does boost::function also handles standard C++11 lambda gracefully?

```
// will this also work?
someFunction([](int x)->void{
    //some implementation
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes this will work.

The important thing is that you shouldn't confuse type *safety* with *compatibility*. You're **not** passing `std::function` *as a* `boost::function`. You're telling the compiler to *wrap* you `std::function` *into a* `boost::function`.

That might not be efficient - as each will add another layer of indirection on invocation. But it will work.

Same thing goes for lambdas: there's nothing magic about lambdas, it's just syntactic sugar for a function object.